# I've recently started coding in android studio for a school project, am having some serious issues and cant fix them, anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Manifest Error:

Merging Errors: Error: tools:replace specified at line:5 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified CovidBlocker.app main manifest (this file), line 4 Error: Validation failed, exiting CovidBlocker.app main manifest (this file)

Manifest:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.covidblocker">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CovidBlocker"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">
        <activity android:name=".settingslocation" />
        <activity android:name=".settingshelp" />
        <activity android:name=".addAccount" />
        <activity android:name=".HomePage" />
        <activity android:name=".CreateAccount" />
        <activity android:name=".Loginpage" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Why did you add this line `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory">` in your manifest? The thing happening right now is you have added this but you are not providing what you have to replace it with.

Comment: i never added anything

Comment: Make sure you pay attention to writing a good title, currently your title applies to every problem and has nothing to do with yours specifically. If every question on SO had that title, it would be quite difficult to find any answers...

Answer (score 1):

try removing `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` line
such as to obtain this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.covidblocker">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CovidBlocker">
        <activity android:name=".settingslocation" />
        <activity android:name=".settingshelp" />
        <activity android:name=".addAccount" />
        <activity android:name=".HomePage" />
        <activity android:name=".CreateAccount" />
        <activity android:name=".Loginpage" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application
</manifest>
```